# A problem of plane geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, plane-geometry

[image]

As the picture shows, there is a circle on the plane of radius $R$ centered at $A$. I found that if a line segment $PQ$ of length $d\ (0<d\leq R)$ **intersecting with** $AB$ satisfies that the endpoint $P$ is **outside the circle**, then $|QB|<d$.

Is there any simple and clear proof for it?

Comment: *"I found that ..."* Please describe how you came to this conclusion. Before I launch into proving someone's conjecture, I prefer to have a sense of its plausibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P$ being outside the circle means that $|AP| > R$. Let's call $S$ the point of intersection of $AB$ and $PQ$. Consider the triangle $ASP$: by the triangle inequality, we get

$$|AP| \leq |AS| + |SP|$$

Analogously, for the triangle $QSB$ we get

$$|QB| \leq |QS| + |SB|$$

Add this two inequalities to get

$$|AP| + |QB| \leq |AS| + |SP| + |QS| + |SB|$$

Now, $AS$ and $SB$ together form the segment $AB$, thus $|AS| + |SB| = |AB| = R$, and similarly $|QS| + |SP| = |QP| = d$. Thus,

$$|AP|+|QB| \leq R+d$$

Moving $|AP|$ to the other side

$$|QB| \leq R + d - |AP| = d - (|AP| - R)$$

Now, $|AP| > R$ implies $|AP|-R>0$, so the right-hand side is strictly less than $d$:

$$|QB| \leq d - (|AP| - R) < d$$

which means

$$|QB| < d$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer!